# How to share a common linux terminal that can be used remotely by 2 or more users ?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, remote-desktop, vnc-server

I want to code/debug collaboratively on a shared linux terminal (so that both parties can see what is being typed into it, and its output) with someone in a remote location. What is the best way to achieve this ?

Options might be:

1. Setting up a tunnel that would allow me to VNC into my partener's
   system. Is this possible without using proprietary software ?
2. Using a web-based terminal, which allows limited disk-space to
   upload a source code file, and then compile/debug it (don't even
   know if such a service is available)

In case option 2 is not available, what is the best way to set up a publicly accessible (over the internet, but secure) VNC in ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using ssh + screen.

Comment: SSH is used to log into a remote machine and execute commands. Screen is used to save a session for your shell. Here's more about using screen for remotely interaction. 

http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442418-using-screen-for-remote-interaction

Comment: I got to understand how screen works - could you tell me how to set up SSH for use over the internet ?